# cannot call method of another class in android

Tags: java, android, android-activity

i try to call the method from `Route` class but when i click submit button , app has stopped unfortunately

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
      final TextView source;
    final TextView destination;
      source = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.source);
      destination = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.destination);

      button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(View v) {
            Routes routes = new Routes();
            routes.start();   
          }
      });
```

Routes.java

```
package com.example.newproject;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;

public class Routes extends Activity {


    public void  start(){
           setContentView(R.layout.routes);

}




}
```

is this right??

```
package com.example.newproject;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;

public class Routes  {


    public void  start(){

        String selva="This is my name";
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), selva, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  


}




}
```

it also shows error message

Comment: yes main activity is works fine when click button it has stopped

Comment: `Routes` is an `Activity`. You cannot just create an instance of a new `Activity`. You need to use `Intents` to start a new `Activity`.

Comment: you can't create instance of activity class and call method like this, you must use normal class or start activity if you want call method inside another activity

Comment: You cannot call activity like this you have to initalize your activity via intent

Comment: You must use intents to navigate to activities.

Comment: could you please answer anyone ! i'm new for android

Comment: You cannot use `new Routes()`.  You cannot treat an `Activity` like a POJO.  As others have said, you need to lean about `Intent`.  As you learn, keep in your head that no other class should try to access anything in  an `Activity`.

Comment: If you wana start the activity "Routes" use "Intent next= new Intent("com.XXX.Activity.NAME"); startActivity(next);"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the second class, being an activity, needs an onCreate() method.
if you want to make a normal class, you must delete "extend activity".
then you can call the method as you did.

Comment: hmm i did like you said and i need to call toast message in new class method , i followed like this package 

com.example.newproject;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;

public class Routes  {

 
 public void  start(){
    
      Toast.makeText( getActivity(), "Called", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
       
            
}
 
  
 
}  it shows also error

Comment: you need to pass the context to the method:

Comment: routes.strart(getApplicationContext());

Comment: and in the class: public void start(Context c){Toast.makeText( c, "Called", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); }

Comment: it works thanks , if i need to call the setContentView(R.layout.routes); in new class how to  do this?

Comment: Please follow the tutorials at developer.android.com.  Only an `Activity` can call `setContentView`.  If you want an activity, then your class must `extend Activity` then the only way to load an activity is to use `Intent`. You are not ready to build apps.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to start a new Activity, in your onClick method you should call `startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Routes.class))`. It will call  automatically the `onCreate()` method in Routes class, so don't forget to override it or your Activity won't start.

Comment: ok if i need to call method of another function how to do that? routes.start(); is it correct?

Comment: You cannot call a method from Activity outside of it like that. There are several ways of making 2 activities communicate but it depends on what you want to do. One way of doing it can be using listeners for example.

Comment: can i get any example for  how to call methods of another class and how to use toast messages?